# What takes so long (4sec) for WinXP x64 to run x86 .NET executable which was fast before ? What VS2008 settings missing?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, sockets, vb6, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have a .NET 3.5 project, usually being compiled as "platform target" x86, "platform" AnySPU, signed. It is being called from inside legacy VB6 process. It was never a problem until recently (may after some Microsoft Updates) it became very slow on start.

Where should I look first to make .NET processes launched faster ? 
Should I add manifest ? Make it trusted and signed ? Change platform target to match CPU ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Slow" launch times for applications could be any number of things, including environmental factors.

If you don't already have it: Add detailed logging to the start-up of your application.

If it's taking more than a second or two before Main() is called (and the codebase isn't overly large or complex), then you may need to look at the system to see if CPU, Memory, or Drives are being pegged, or are slow responding.